# How to fill in missing values by group?

Tags: stata, missing-data

I have the following data structure. Within each group, some observations have missing `value`. I do know that each group has only one non-missing value (`10` for group 1 and `11` for group 2 in this case). The location of the missing observations are random within the group (i.e. can't fill in missing values with the previous / following value).

How to fill the missing values with the one non-missing value by group?

```
group  value
1       .
1       10
1       .
2       11
2       .
2       11
```

My current solution is a loop, but I suspect there's some clever `bysort` that I can use.

```
levelsof group, local(lm_group)
foreach group in `lm_group' {
    levelsof value if group == `group', local(lm_value)
    replace value = `lm_value' if group == `group'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you know that the non-missing values are constant within group, then you can get there in one with

```
 bysort group (value) : replace value = value[_n-1] if missing(value)
```

as the missing values are first sorted to the end and then each missing value is `replace`d by the previous non-missing value. Replacement cascades downwards, but only within each group.

For documentation, see [this FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/)

To check that there is at most one distinct non-missing value within each group, you could do this:

```
bysort group (value) : assert (value == value[1]) | missing(value)
```

More personal note. It's nice to see `levelsof` in use, as I first wrote it, but the above is better.

Answer (score 4):

I think the xfill command is what you are looking for.

To install `xfill`, copy-paste the following into Stata and follow instructions:

```
net from http://www.sealedenvelope.com/
```

After that, the rest is easy:

```
xfill value, i(group)
```

You can read up about `xfill` [here](https://www.sealedenvelope.com/stata/xfill/)

Answer (score 1):

The clever bysort-answer you were looking for was:

```
bysort group: egen new_value=max(cond(!missing(value), value, .)
```

The cond-function checks if the first argument is true and returns value if is and . if it is not.

Comment: That's going to work but it would be simpler to write `bysort group egen new_value = max(value)` which gives the same result in the conditions of the question (that there is at most one non-missing value in each group). If you look inside the code for `egen` and also for its `max()` function (which on your system will be inside `_gmax.ado`) you will see that this solution requires the user to type one line (good) and Stata to execute dozens of lines of code (not so good). The solution in my earlier answer requires Stata to execute one line of code.

Comment: There is a colon missing in my previous comment. Should be `bysort group:` and so forth.

Answer (score -1):

FWIW I could not get Nick's bysort solution to work, no clue why. I followed the suggested syntax from the FAQ he linked instead and got it to work, though. The generic form is:

```
gsort id -myvar
by id: replace myvar = myvar[_n-1] if myvar == .
```

EDIT: fixed the errant reference to "time" in the previous iteration of this post (and added the if missing condition). The current code should be a functioning generic solution.

Comment: This code -- when corrected to if myvar == . -- will work for data with a time variable in which the  non-missing values happen to be last in time. In no sense is it a generic solution for the problem in the question where the problem is that "missing observations" (meaning, observations with missing values) "are random within the group.

Comment: Thanks, I believe my edits addressed your comments.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. However, this now just duplicates the accepted answer insofar as it is equivalent to `bysort id (myvar) : replace myvar = myvar[_n-1] if myvar == .`  (the qualifier is a slight specialization of `if missing(myvar)`.